# Can't send DHT11 data to MySQL

Tags: c#, php, mysql, arduino

I have been given a task about Arduino temperature and humidity sensor. I have created a database using MySQL and I have created a PHP file to display and receive data from the Arduino IDE. Then I have checked the coding many times and modified it so many times but it's still can't send data to PHP.

This my code to add to MySQL (read_temperature)

```
<?php
$server = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$db_name = 'datawebserver';
$conn = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $db_name);
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'Connection to database failed : '.mysqli_connect_errno();
}
$ahum1 = $_POST['humidity'];
$&temp1 = $_POST['temperature'];
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO 'templog' ('temperature', 'humidity') VALUES ('".$&temp1."', '".$ahum1."')");
mysqli_close($conn);
header('Location: index.php');
?>
```

This is the display data code from MySQL:

```
<?php
// ======= start connect.php ======= //
$server = 'localhost'; // default : localhost
$username = 'root'; // default : root
$password = '';
$db_name = 'datawebserver';
$conn = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $db_name);
// Check the connection
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'Connection to database failed : '.mysqli_connect_error();
}
// ======= end connect.php ======= //
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM templog ORDER BY timeStamp DESC");
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sensor Data</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Temperature / moisture sensor readings</h1>
    <table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;Timestamp&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;Temperature 1&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;Moisture 1&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <?php
      if($result) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          echo '<tr>';
          echo '<td>&nbsp;'.$row['timeStamp'].'&nbsp;</td>';
          echo '<td>&nbsp;'.$row['temperature'].'&nbsp;</td>';
          echo '<td>&nbsp;'.$row['humidity'].'&nbsp;</td>';
          echo '</tr>';
        }
        // free result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
      }
      // tutup connection mysqli
      mysqli_close($conn);
      ?>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is the code for the Arduino IDE:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <DHT.h>
#include <String.h>
// ---------------------------------------------- Web Server CONFIG
// Enter a MAC address and IP address for your controller below.
// The IP address will be dependent on your local network:
byte mac[] = {0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
IPAddress ip(10,10,1,253);
IPAddress gateway(10,10,1,1);
IPAddress subnet(255,255,255,0);
EthernetClient client;
// ---- Humidity Module CONFIG
#define DHTPIN A0 // What pin we're connected to
#define DHTTYPE DHT11 // DHT 11
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Serial connection established");
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
  }
  dht.begin();
  Serial.println("DHT11 connection established");
}

void loop() {
  delay(1000);
  // ---- Humidity Module ACTION
  Serial.println("Humidity Module ACTION");
  // Wait a few seconds between measurements.
  int t = 0; // temperature
  int h = 0; // humidity
  String data = "";
  // Reading temperature or humidity takes about 250 milliseconds!
  // Sensor readings may also be up to 2 seconds 'old' 
  // (its a very slow sensor)
  h = dht.readHumidity();
  delay(500);
  // Read temperature as Celsius (the default)
  t = dht.readTemperature();
  delay(500);
  // Check if any reads failed and exit early (to try again).
  if (isnan(h) || isnan(t)) {
   Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT sensor!");
   return;
  }
  // The Serial.print & Serial.println commands are optional
  // (I used them for testing purposes)  
  Serial.print("Temp: ");
  Serial.println(t);
  Serial.print("Hum: ");
  Serial.println(h);  
  // Preparing the data from the sensors to send via the 
  // ethernet shield
  data = "ahum1=" + String(h) + "&temp1=" + String(t);
  Serial.println(data);    // For testing purposes
  // ---- Ethernet Shield ACTION
  if (client.connect("127.0.0.1", 80)) {
    // Your domain
    Serial.println("Client connected.");
    client.println("POST arduino4/read_temperature.php HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: 127..0.0.1"); // Your domain
    client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println("User-Agent: Arduino/1.0");
    client.print("Content-Length: ");
    client.println(data.length());
    client.println();
    client.println(data);
  }
  if (client.connected()) {
    client.stop();
  }
  // Now wait approximately one hour
  // 1000ms * 60 = 60 000ms = 1 min
  // 60 000ms * 60 = 3 600 000ms = 1 h
  // The delay() function should know it's a long int, 
  // that's why there is a 'L' included at the end
  delay(3600000L);
}
```

BTW I have zero knowledge about Arduino so I apologize in advance if I ask stupid questions.

Comment: Can you also provide all the output that the Serial.println generates?
This line 'client.println("Host: 127..0.0.1");' has to many dots in IP address, should be   client.println("Host: 127.0.0.1");

Comment: i already correct that mistake but its still didn't sent the data to php...

Comment: The line 'client.connect("127.0.0.1", 80)' looks suspicious. Since your network is 10.10.1.0/24 I think that the server running php should be in that subnet. Please verify IP address of machine running php part.